# Best way to lock SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing a C++ application that is connecting to a SQL Server database via ODBC.

I need an Archive function so I'm going to write a stored procedure that takes a date. It will total up all the transactions and payments prior to that date for each customer, update the customer's starting balance accordingly, and then delete all transactions and payments prior to that date.

It occurs to me that it could be very bad if someone else is adding or deleting transactions or payments at the same time this stored procedure runs. Therefore, I'm thinking I should lock the entire database during execution, which would not happen that often.

I'm curious if my logic is good and what would be the best way to lock the entire database for such a purpose.

**UPDATE:**

Based on user12069178's answer, here's what I've come up with so far. Would appreciate any feedback on it.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ArchiveData] @ArchiveDateTime DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
    (
        CustomerId INT,
        Amount BIGINT
    );

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    -- Archive transactions
    DELETE Transactions WITH (TABLOCK)
    OUTPUT deleted.CustomerId, deleted.TotalAmount INTO @TempTable
    WHERE [TimeStamp] < @ArchiveDateTime;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TempTable)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Customers SET StartingBalance = StartingBalance +
        (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @TempTable temp WHERE Id = temp.CustomerId)
    END;

    DELETE FROM @TempTable

    -- Archive payments
    DELETE Payments WITH (TABLOCK)
    OUTPUT deleted.CustomerId, deleted.Amount INTO @TempTable
    WHERE [Date] < @ArchiveDateTime;

    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TempTable)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE Customers SET StartingBalance = StartingBalance -
        (SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM @TempTable temp WHERE Id = temp.CustomerId)
    END;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

Comment: Presumably if the users have the ability to change past history then you don't want to be deleting those records anyway. As a rule we would *never* want to lock a database, and if we need concurrency controls then we use transactions.

Comment: @TomC: I don't believe a transaction would prevent another user adding a payment between the time I calculate the balance and delete the old rows. As far as the ability to archive old data, QuickBooks allows me to do that so I'm not the only person who thinks it might be useful.

Comment: Agree, though from an accounting perspective they would have a locked period (like locking last financial year) and you simply cant update any records for the old periods. I'm not sure how they do that - its either in code, or it could be done through triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the way to make sure that the rows you are deleting are the ones that you are totalling and inserting is to use the OUTPUT clause while deleting. It can output the rows that were selected for deletion.

Here's a setup that will give us some transactions:

```
USE tempdb;
GO

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Transactions;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Transactions
(
    TransactionID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_dbo_Transactions
        PRIMARY KEY,
    TransactionAmount decimal(18,2) NOT NULL,
    TransactionDate date NOT NULL
);
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Counter int = 1;
WHILE @Counter <= 50
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Transactions 
    (
        TransactionAmount, TransactionDate
    )
    VALUES (ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % 10 + 1, DATEADD(day, 0 - @Counter * 3, GETDATE()));

    SET @Counter += 1;
END;

SELECT * FROM dbo.Transactions;
GO
```

Now the following code deletes the rows past a cutoff, and concurrently outputs the amounts into a table variable, and then inserts the total row into the transactions table.

```
DECLARE @CutoffDate date = DATEADD(day, 1, EOMONTH(DATEADD(month, -2, GETDATE())));
DECLARE @TransactionAmounts TABLE
(
    TransactionAmount decimal(18,2)
);

BEGIN TRAN;

DELETE dbo.Transactions WITH (TABLOCK)
OUTPUT deleted.TransactionAmount INTO @TransactionAmounts 
WHERE TransactionDate < @CutoffDate;

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TransactionAmounts)
BEGIN
    INSERT dbo.Transactions (TransactionAmount, TransactionDate)
    SELECT SUM(TransactionAmount), DATEADD(day, 1, @CutoffDate)
    FROM @TransactionAmounts;
END;

COMMIT;
```

I usually try to avoid specifying locks whenever possible but based on your suggestion, I've added it. If you didn't have the table lock, it'd still be ok but would mean that even if someone adds in a new "old" row while you're doing this, it won't be in the total or deleted either. Making the transaction serializable would also achieve the outcome and would lock less than the table lock if the number of rows being deleted was less than the lock escalation threshold (defaults to 5000).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From what I can understand, that seems like a reasonable approach. I'm not sure that your code handles every customer. Also, I need to consider both the *Transactions* and *Payments* table (not just the *Transactions* table). I've reworked your code and posted in my question. I'd appreciate if you could comment on that code. For one thing, does the temporary table get cleaned up by itself? Also, am I clearing the results from the first set correctly?

Comment: It's a pretty general approach and works well. The only comments I'd make on the proc are that as well as the SET NOCOUNT ON line, I'd be keen to also see SET XACT_ABORT ON to make sure that you get a transaction abort on a statement abort. Also, it'd be better to call the table something more meaningful, for the same reason you wouldn't call an integer variable @integer. But otherwise, all good. Hope it helps.

Comment: One more thing: if you're using the table variable for two entirely different reasons, use two table variables instead, and name each of them for what they hold.

Comment: Does the temp table clean itself up automatically?

Comment: It's a table variable, so like other variables, it gets destroyed as soon as it goes out of scope (i.e. batch, or procedure). For this sort of thing, far less painful than actual temporary tables, except when you get to much larger numbers of rows.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Note that the number of rows could potentially be in the thousands. Should I consider a temporary table then?

Comment: For thousands I'm not too worried. It's only an amount, and you're only adding it up. It would be different if you were needing to index it for some reason.